# scrollbar track appears randomly

Tags: html, css, angular, scroll, scrollbar

I'd like for my divs to not have that white area (where the scroll bar thumb appears). I'm not sure how to recreate this because it appears randomly on chrome and safari.

[image]

this is the div

```
.column-content{
  height:60vh;
  padding: 10px 3px 0 3px;
  overflow:scroll;
  touch-action: none;
  @media screen and (min-height:1100px){
    height: 70vh;
  }
}
```

I need it scrollable but I also don't want that ugly white bar to show up... I've tried setting the webkit scroll track on my index.html file but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you are searching for the webkit-scrollbar ?

```
.column-content::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

but as it is webkit, it's not compatible with all browsers.
aslo you set `overflow:scroll`, do you need scrolling on the two axis ? if not, you can consider setting it to `auto`.

Comment: I really only need it to be on the y axis. Anyways, I'm not sure if your fix would actually work because the track appears randomly as I said in the post.

Comment: in order to help you, I need to reproduce the bug, so can you create a snippet with the bug reproduced ? half of the time you find the error doing that, and else, we could see the problem

Comment: lol the problem is that i haven't been able to reproduce it. Like i said, it happens randomly on anything I have a scroll property on. I was hoping that by providing a picture of the problem, someone who has dealt with it might know what's going on

Comment: I'm sorry then, it never happened to me this way. Even with your entire code you can't reproduce it ?

Comment: nope I believe it has something to do with overflow: scroll. It happened again and i turned it to overflow: auto and it got rid of the bars.

Comment: so my fix worked ? don't hesitate to comment here if it appears again ;)